# Use Windbg to debug win2008

Tags: vmware, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2

I use Windbg+vmware debug win2008. And in win2008, I set the config of debug like:

```
bcdedit /dbgsettings serial baudrate:115200 debugport:1
bcdedit /debug {current} ON
```

Then, I use serial port at named pipe type in VM. I set "\.\pipe\com_1" and select "This end is the server" and "The other end is an application" item.

Finaly, I set Windbg like:

```
-b -k com:port=\\.\pipe\com_1,baud=115200,pipe
```

When I run Windbg, it display:

```
Opened \\.\pipe\com_1
Waiting to reconnect...
```

and no response. I think Windbg find com_1. But I do not know win2008 has no response. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e1039e4f-56aa-4f1a-90bf-2662b37cd4f3) solution. You write: I set "`\.\pipe\com_1`", should be `\\.\pipe\com_1`

Comment: Thank you, sergmat! the solution is useful. I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/e1039e4f-56aa-4f1a-90bf-2662b37cd4f3) solution. You write: I set "`\.\pipe\com_1`", should be `\\.\pipe\com_1`